# Characterization of growth in terms of coarse algebraic topology

Tags: homotopy-theory, geometric-group-theory, coarse-geometry

$$
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
\newcommand{\mbb}[1]{\mathbb{#1}}
\newcommand{\opn}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
\DeclareMathOperator\cap{cap}
\def\sse{\subseteq}
$$

**Coarse spaces**

Let $X$ be a coarse space, i.e. a set equipped with a subset $\mathcal{E}$ of the powerset $\wp(X\times X)$ such that $\mathcal{E}$ is closed under inverses, finite unions, products (compositions), subsets, and contains the diagonal. The set $ \mc{E}$ is called *coarse structure* or the set of *entourages*.

**Capacity with respect to an entourage**

Define the capacity of a subset $S\subseteq X$ with respect to symmetric subset $E\subseteq X\times X$ as the largest number $m$ for which there exist distinct points $y_1,\ldots,y_m\in S$ such that no pair $(y_i,y_j)_{i\neq j}$ belongs to $E.$ We denote capacity of $S$ w.r.t. $E$ as $\operatorname{cap}_E(S).$

**$E$-balls**

For a subset $E\subseteq X\times X$ and a point $x\in X$ denote by $E_x$ the $E$-*ball* centered at $x,$ that is:$$
E_x=\{x'\in E\mid (x',x)\in E\}.
$$

**Universal bounded geometry coarse structures**

We call a symmetric subset $E\subseteq X\times X$ containing the diagonal *gauge*. A subset $F\subseteq X\times X$ is called *uniform* w.r.t. $E$ if the values of $\cap_E(F[E_x])$ and $\cap_E(F^{-1}[E_x])$ are uniformly bounded in $x.$

For a fixed gauge $E$ the set of all uniform subsets in $X\times X$ forms a coarse structure [Roe, Proposition 3.7.](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Lectures-on-coarse-geometry-Roe/d1ead7c7bc5294a7658c280fba596873a3cd0860) Such coarse structure is called *universal bounded geometry coarse structure*.

A coarse structure $\mc{E}$ has *bounded geometry* it is finer than universal bounded geometry coarse structure for some gauge $E$ on $X.$

**Growth functions**

Let $(X,\mc{E})$ be a coarse space. Assume that $\mc{E}$ has bounded geometry finer than universal geometry defined by gauge $E$. For $F\in \mathcal{E}$ define the growth function of $F$ at a point $x\in X$ as the capacity:
$$
\operatorname{gr}_{F,x}:n\mapsto \operatorname{cap}_E((F^n)_x)
$$

We say that the coarse space $(X,\mc{E})$ has growth type $f$ for some $f:\mbb{N}\to \mbb{N}$ if for every $F\sse X\times X$ we have $\opn{gr}_{F,x}\preceq f$ with respect to the usual (in geometric group theory) order relation on such functions and there is at least one pair $F,x$ such that $f\preceq \opn{gr}_{F,x}.$

**Homotopy theory**

There is a way to define the homotopy theory of coarse spaces and coarse maps using an appropriate coarse interval, see e.g. [Norouzizadeh Chapter 3] for this construction. Another more high-brow way of doing the same thing is given (if I understand correctly) by a motivic construction of [Bunke and Engel, Section I.3](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-51335-1).

**The question**

Is there a way to recover the growth function of a coarse space with bounded geometry in the sense of [Roe, Chapter 3](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Lectures-on-coarse-geometry-Roe/d1ead7c7bc5294a7658c280fba596873a3cd0860) from coarse homotopy invariants of this space (in the sense of [Bunke and Engel](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-51335-1) or [Norouzizadeh](https://d-nb.info/1000018849/34))?

**EDIT:** It was pointed out in the [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/437632/characterization-of-growth-in-terms-of-coarse-algebraic-topology?noredirect=1#comment1128220_437632) that I should explain all the definitions from the question for it to make any sense. I did that to the best of my abilities, although maybe the result became too lengthy.

Comment: You will probably get a better response if you define the terminology you are using, in as elementary a form as possible.  Most users won't download or purchase a book to answer a question.

Comment: @RyanBudney Yes, you are absolutely right. I probably should have done so in the initial post. I just thought for some mysterious reason that everyone knows everything (up to page numbers etc.)